# QtCreator shows "Expression too complex" when debugging with CDB

Tags: visual-studio-2017, qt5, qt-creator, windbg

**My environment: Qt5.14.2 + QtCreator4.14.2 + MSVC2017**

When I debug programs in QtCreator with CDB, I cannot see the variable's value from using cursor pointing to the variable, but says "Expression too complex"(See the picture below), I googled and test some solutions, including change CDB configurations, download CDB symbols, but none of them works. So hope someone familiar with this could help me out, Thanks for advance.

[image: Debug information]

Comment: did you figure out?

Comment: Seems like this bug-report https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-24180 is related. It is mentioned that after a clean-rebuild, it is OK (as long as source-code is unchanged).

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work, and I gave up this problem now, because I don't use the debug function often, thanks for your reply